# How to split string in MongoDB?

Tags: regex, mongodb

The example data is as following:

```
{"BrandId":"a","Method":"PUT","Url":"/random/widgets/random/state"}
{"BrandId":"a","Method":"POST","Url":"/random/collection/random/state"}
{"BrandId":"b","Method":"PUT","Url":"/random/widgets/random/state"}
{"BrandId":"b","Method":"PUT","Url":"/random/widgets/random/state"}
```

I need to find all the rows with method=put and Url in a pattern /random/widgets/random/state. "random" is a random string with a fixed length. the expected result is :

```
{"BrandId":"a","total":1}
{"BrandId":"b","total":2}
```

I tried to write so code as :

```
db.accessLog.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: '$BrandId',
        total: {
                $sum:{
                  $cond:[{$and: [ {$eq: ['$Method', 'POST']},
                        {Url:{$regex: /.*\/widgets.*\/state$/}} ]}, 1, 0]
                }
            },
    {$group: {
        _id: '$_id',
       total:{$sum:'$total'}
    }
])
```

but the regular expression does not work, so I suppose I need to try other way to do it, perhaps split string. And I need to use $cond. please keep it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to achieve what you want, I assume the data in a collection named **'products'**

```
db.products.aggregate([
                {$match : {'Method':'PUT','Url':/.*widgets.*\/state$/ }},
                {$group: {'_id':'$BrandId','total':{$sum: 1} }}
        ]);
```

**1. $match:**
Find all documents that has 'PUT' method and Url in the specified pattern.

**2. $group:** Group by brand Id and for each entry, count 1

Comment: Sorry, I need to put the code under $cond as I mentioned. Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: Instead of {$regex: /.*\/widgets.*\/state$/}, use /.*widgets.*\/state$/

Comment: I have complicated code, and I need a solution can be used under $cond. and regular expression can not work, that is why I ask this question.

Comment: You can use my code to achieve what you want, it is far more simpler. Other than that, I cannot help

Comment: sorry, you code is something I already know. I need to put it under $cond, so I ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

[Greedy matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) is the problem.

Assuming non-zero number of 'random' characters (sounds sensible), try a regex of:

```
/[^\/]+\/widgets\/[^\/]+\/state$/
```

Comment: Sorry, I suppose regular expression does not work in $cond. as I mentioned that I need another way to do it.

Comment: Looks like [you can't do that](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator). Perhaps you should just filter your collection before aggregating, i.e. use a `$match` with `$regex` ([which *is* supported](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/#query-selectors)).